# HP LaserJet 1020 doesn't print

Tags: windows-7, printer

I've got a HP LaserJet 1020 printer connected to my 64-bit Windows 7 Ultimate machine.  I'm sharing this printer out.  Got another 64-bit Windows 7 machine, with Home Premium.  I installed the printer driver from HP for 64-bit on both machines.  However, the strange thing is that if the Home Premium machine prints something, it never comes out unless I reboot the Ultimate machine.

This is less than optimal.

Any idea what's causing this and if there's anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alternative to sharing printers is to use a usb print server. I've used my Netgear PS121 for years on various HP printers. Your LaserJet is not specifically mentioned, but I imagine it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: http://www.sevenforums.com/drivers/20537-installing-sharing-hp-laserjet-1020-win7-x64.html .

It might help you. I don't think there is a permanent solution, but nevertheless.